# Pool mining website need to be logged in?

Tags: miner-configuration

Do i need to be logged in on the website mining pool to mine coins? Can i log off the pool mining website and just leave cudaminer running and still mine coins in the mining pool?

Comment: Most likely you do not need to be logged in, but since you didn't say what coin you are mining or what pool you are using, it's impossible to say for certain.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be logged in all the time. You just need to leave your miner (cudaminer) running.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't worry. It's just a controlpanel-style thing for keeping you informed; you don't need to stay logged in to that frontend in order to earn your poole shares.

Make sure to keep your actual miner running though: most OSes allow to conveniently put it in the background (so you can log out of your box, too) while running your miners and earning coins.